# Discount value in Stupid Backoff

Tags: python, nlp, smoothing

I'm following the NLP tutorial [here](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/19) (6'58'') - section about stupid-backoff smoothing algorithm. 
In the tutorial video and the [implementation of bi-gram level stupid-backoff](https://github.com/gpoulter/nlp-pa2-autocorrect/blob/master/python/StupidBackoffLanguageModel.py), they use a discount value = 0.4

[image: Tutorial Slide]

Implement of bigram-level backoff:

```
def score(self, sentence):
    score = 0.0
    previous = sentence[0]
    for token in sentence[1:]:
        bicount = self.bigramCounts[(previous, token)]
        bi_unicount = self.unigramCounts[previous]
        unicount = self.unigramCounts[token]
        if bicount > 0:
            score += math.log(bicount)
            score -= math.log(bi_unicount)
        else:
            score += math.log(0.4)     // discount here
            score += math.log(unicount + 1)
            score -= math.log(self.total + self.vocab_size)
        previous = token
    return score
```

But then in [trigram-level implementation](https://github.com/gpoulter/nlp-pa2-autocorrect/blob/master/python/CustomLanguageModel.py), discount value is 1.

```
def score(self, sentence):
    score = 0.0
    fst = sentence[0]
    snd = sentence[1]
    for token in sentence[2:]:
        tricount = self.trigramCounts[(fst, snd, token)]
        tri_bicount = self.bigramCounts[(fst, snd)]
        bicount = self.bigramCounts[(snd, token)]
        bi_unicount = self.unigramCounts[snd]
        unicount = self.unigramCounts[token]
        if tricount > 0:
            score += math.log(tricount)
            score -= math.log(tri_bicount)
        elif bicount > 0:
            score += math.log(bicount)             // no discount here
            score -= math.log(bi_unicount)
        else:
            score += math.log((unicount + 1))      // no discount here
            score -= math.log(self.total + self.vocab_size)
        fst, snd = snd, token
    return score
```

when I ran the [project](https://github.com/gpoulter/nlp-pa2-autocorrect/tree/master/python) - with both discount set to 0.4 and 1 for the tri-gram level, I got the score:

`tri-gram with discount = 0.4` < `bi-gram with discount = 0.4` < `tri-gram with discount =1`

It's easy to know why - with discount = 0.4, the final `else` of tri-gram become:

```
else:
    score += math.log(0.4)      // -> -0.3979
    score += math.log(0.4)      // -> -0.3979
    score += math.log((unicount + 1))      // no discount here
    score -= math.log(self.total + self.vocab_size)
```

So i'm really confused - where's the 0.4 value came from ?

Comment: the 0.4 in stupid backoff?

Comment: @user3639557 yes, but I don't know why it's 0.4 and why in the trigram example, they don't use this discount.

Comment: it's pretty arbitrary, that's why they refer to it as stupid-backoff. read the paper cited in the following answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the google [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D07-1090.pdf) proposing the stupid backoff.